# Vários eventos de componentes em apenas um método

Tags: c#, wpf, eventos

eu tenho varios eventos de meus textbox, o problema é que tenho uns 30 em meu formulário.
Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma para eu melhorar meu código, reduzir ele criando apenas um método para controlar todos esses eventos.

Três eventos de exemplo do TextBox:

```
    private void textEmpPrefixo_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var elemento = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;

        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            elemento.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            elemento.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous));
        }
    }

    private void textEmpTelefones_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var elemento = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;

        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            elemento.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            elemento.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous));
        }
    }

    private void textEmpObs2_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        var elemento = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;

        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            elemento.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.Up)
        {
            elemento.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous));
        }
    }
```

Eu Utilizo eles para mudar de foco conforme eles utilizam a seta ou para cima ou para baixo
Utilizo a tecnologia c# wpf.

Agradeço desde já (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode ter apenas um handler e nos `TextBox` no evento `KeyUp` chamar o handler.

```
private void MudarFoco_keyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var elemento = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;

    if(e.Key == Key.Down)
        elemento.MoveFocus(New TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));

    if(e.Key == Key.Up)
       elemento.MoveFocus(newTraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Previous));
}
```

e no evento do `TextBox`;

```
KeyUp="MudarFoco_KeyUp";
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou. Caso eu esteja aplicando no padrão MVVM, esse método ficaria na View mesmo ne?

Comment: Se a resposta lhe ajudou, marque-a como certa!

Comment: @Emerson, sim fica na `view`, no caso no `codebehind` do arquivo `.xml`.

Comment: Obrigado. só não consigo marcar como útil a resposta porque preciso de 15 de reputação..

Comment: Só uma pequena nota em relação à terminologia: o método `MudarFoco_keyUp` não é um evento - é um event handler. `KeyUp` é um evento.

Comment: Ok amigo... Blz ^^